# PyQt5 (Python): Get value from qpushbutton by contextmenu

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I created a few `qpushbuttons` in a `for` loop. What I want to do is to access their values (the number which the for loop iterates) by a context menu.

I can create the buttons and with left click, I get their values printed. But when I open a context menu on right click, the triggered command `self.value.triggered.connect(partial(self.get_value, number))` only returns the highest value.

What do I have to change in order to get the value by the `get_value` entry from the context menu?

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QAction, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        self.buttons = []
        self.value = []
        self.context_menu = []
        pos_value = [30, 50]
        for number in range(0,4):
            button_text = "Button " + str(number)
            self.buttons.append(QPushButton(button_text, self))
            self.buttons[number].move(*pos_value)
            self.buttons[number].clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
            pos_value[0] += 120

            self.buttons[number].setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            self.buttons[number].customContextMenuRequested.connect(partial(self.open_context_menu, number))
            self.context_menu.append(QMenu(self))
            self.value.append(QAction('Get value ' + str(number), self))
            self.context_menu[-1].addAction(self.value[-1])
            self.value[-1].triggered.connect(partial(self.get_value, number))

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 150)
        self.show()

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender.text() + ' was pressed')

    def get_value(self, value):
        print('Value ' + str(value))

    def open_context_menu(self, i, point):
        self.context_menu[-1].exec_(self.buttons[i].mapToGlobal(point))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT: I found an error in my program, because I have overwritten the variables self.value and self.context_menu. Now this has been fixed, but the error remains.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def open_context_menu(self, i, point):
    self.context_menu[-1].exec_(self.buttons[i].mapToGlobal(point))
#                     ^
#               Your bug here
```

Comment: thank you so much: self.context_menu[i].exec_(self.buttons[i].mapToGlobal(point)) is the solution to my problem